# SpringBoot jar - missing resources for webapp

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

The problem is that my resources for webapp are missing for springboot application build with maven as jar. I think that I have messed something up and after a googling session, I am still out of ideas how to solve a problem of

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/static/index.html
```

after going to localhost:8080/login from jar.

Mvn build:

```
<build>
     <resources>
       <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp/</directory>
       </resource>
     </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <executions>
                <execution>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
             </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is my eclipse project structure:
[image: project structure]

Besides, I have a configuration class

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.staszkox.*" })
@Import({ SecurityConfiguration.class })
public class ResourcesResolver extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter 
{
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/static/");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) 
    {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}


@Controller
public class ResourcesController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) 
    {
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

Do you have any ideas what could be wrong here? I have tried every resources folder setup in target folder with jar and still nothing. Everything works fine, if I run the application from eclipse.

Comment: what template engine are you using? usually you do not return the suffix for a template - only its name. So I would try a: return "index" without the .html

Comment: When you have jsps, You have to package as war instead of jar. Still u can run as jar executable like java -jar yourapp.war

Comment: @kswauhgs Yes, it works with war packaging! Thank you so much! Could you please explain why?